# Both modals triggered on click

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have two modals that have their own buttons to trigger them and be hidden when the page loads with javascript instead of data attributes. Currently, they both trigger on page load and both pop up when I click either button for the login or reserve table button. Here is my code:

Home
                     About
                     Menu
                     Contact
                
                
                    
                         Login

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" id="btnCloselogin" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-auto">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>        
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<header class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-header">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 align-self-center">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 align-self-center btn btn-warning btn-block">
                <a href="" 
                title="Or Call us at <br><strong>+852 12345678</strong>" 
                href="" id="reservebutton">Reserve Table</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Reserve a Table</h1>

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div>
                    <form class="inline">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number of Guests</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">3</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">4</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">5</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">6</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="Section">Section</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle col-sm-4" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-success active">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-smoking
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Date and Time</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" placeholder="Time">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mt-2">
                                <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto" id="reserveCancel">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </form>
                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#loginModal').modal({ show: false})
    $('#loginModal').modal(function(){
        $("#loginbutton").click(function(){
            $("#loginModal").modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                show: false
            });
        }); 
    });

</script>
<script>
    $('#reserveModal').modal({ show: false})
    $('#reserveModal').modal(function(){
        $("#reservebutton").click(function(){
            $("#reserveModal").modal({
                backdrop: 'static',
                show: false
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Just trying to keep it as simple as possible so the clearest way I can do this would be appreciated (I'm new to JS :) ) Thank you for your time.

I also want to note that I have this Jquery code for a carousel in the index.html with the rest which works fine:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#mycarousel').carousel({ interval: 2000 });
        $('#carouselButton').click(function() {
            if ($('#carouselButton').children('span').hasClass('fa-pause')){
                $('#mycarousel').carousel('pause');
                $('#carouselButton').children('span').removeClass('fa-pause');
                $('#carouselButton').children('span').addClass('fa-play');
            }
            else if ($('#carouselButton').children('span').hasClass('fa-play')){
                $('#mycarousel').carousel('cycle');
                $('#carouselButton').children('span').removeClass('fa-play');
                $('#carouselButton').children('span').addClass('fa-pause');
            }
        });
```

});

Comment: I just want to note for everyone to see that I also have this Jquery code for a carousel which works:

Answer (score 0):

Where are you declaring the script tags?

Generally, you'll run to place the script in the  if you want the script to run for some event.

You'll also want to attach the event handlers when the document is loaded, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reservebutton").click(function(){
          $('#reserveModal').dialog('open');
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Oh great, I actually took the return false event handler and added it to Markipe's code suggestion and it works!!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modal function does not support a function as an argument, that you are doing in the script tag, to show and hide the modal you just have to update the show property via the modal's options argument on Click.
Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
          <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" id="btnCloselogin" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button id="login">Login</button>
    <button id="reserve">Reserve</button>

    <div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1>Reserve a Table</h1>

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div>
                        <form class="inline">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Number of Guests</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">3</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">4</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">5</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">6</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mb-2">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="Section">Section</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle col-sm-4" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-success active">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-smoking
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger">
                                    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Date and Time</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="Date">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="time" class="form-control" id="time" placeholder="Time">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row mt-2">
                                <div class="col">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ml-auto" id="reserveCancel">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Jquery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#login').on('click', function() {
        $('#loginModal').modal({ show: true });
    });

    $('#reserve').on('click', function() {
        $('#reserveModal').modal({ show: true })
    });
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after adjusting it to the above Jquery code when I click on the buttons the screen kind of fades for a quick second then nothing happens. I tried something else which I found online that did the same thing, the code that I posted seems to be the only thing that actually loads the modals (that I have found so far), although it always does both. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets break it down:

First you don't need to declare/hide a bootrstrap modal on load. Basically **.modal** is already set to **display: none;** on page load. So you can remove this line:

```
$('#loginModal').modal({ show: false})
```

Next is you wanted to show the modal after a certain button was click.

```
$("#loginbutton").click(function(){
     $(".modal").modal('hide'); /* to close other open modals */
     $("#loginModal").modal({
          backdrop: 'static', /* backdrop is set to 'static' if you don't want to close the modal by by clicking outside the modal.  */
          show: true /* it should be set to true, not false so modal will show */
     });
});
```

You don't need to enclosed the function in `$('#loginModal').modal(function(){ });`. Its proper to enclosed jQuery functions in `$(document).ready(function() { });` instead.

So this should be your complete script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginbutton").click(function(){
        $(".modal").modal('hide'); 
        $("#loginModal").modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            show: true
        });
    }); 
    $("#reservebutton").click(function(){
        $(".modal").modal('hide'); 
        $("#reserveModal").modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
            show: true
        });
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Markipe, thanks for offering advice. I inputted the code into my script and the same thing happens which I commented on the above advice from Swaraj Gandhi, the screen flickers or fades for a second then nothing else happens. Any further suggestions?

Comment: I've used laujonat's suggestion to add an event handler to your code and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, oh I see. Im just wondering are you using a links as your buttons? if so yes definitely, you have to add event handler. You could either return false or preventDefault().